# Why must $a$ and $b$ both be coprime when proving that the square root of two is irrational?

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

Suppose we wish to prove that the square root of two is irrational. We begin by assuming that it is rational.  Namely, where both $a$ and $b$ are integers $$\frac{a}{b} = \sqrt 2 
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% faaagCart1ev2aaaKnaaaaWenf2ys9wBH5garuavP1wzZbqedmvETj
% 2BSbqefm0B1jxALjharqqtubsr4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0x
% bbL8FesqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaq
% pepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-xfr-xb9Gqpi0dc9adbaqaaeGaciGa
% aiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaWaaSaaaeaacaWGHbaabaGaamOyaaaacq
% GH9aqpdaGcaaqaaiaaikdaaSqabaaaaa!31D3!
$$

Why is it so important that both $a$ and $b$ be coprime and the fraction be irreducible?  That is, if $a$ and $b$ are not coprime and the fraction is indeed reducible, then$$\frac{a}{b} \ne \sqrt 2 
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% faaagCart1ev2aaaKnaaaaWenf2ys9wBH5garuavP1wzZbqedmvETj
% 2BSbqefm0B1jxALjharqqtubsr4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0x
% bbL8FesqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaq
% pepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-xfr-xb9Gqpi0dc9adbaqaaeGaciGa
% aiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaWaaSaaaeaacaWGHbaabaGaamOyaaaacq
% GHGjsUdaGcaaqaaiaaikdaaSqabaaaaa!3294!
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assume that $a,b$ are coprime (which you are entitled to do by properties of the rationals), then you may proceed by [contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction).  This is not strictly necessary, it's just simpler than the alternatives, like [infinite descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent).

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand. We are trying to find a ratio of integers that equals the square root of two. Such a ratio must be irreducible.  Suppose a reducible fraction satisfies the first equation, then its reduced fractions must also satisfy the first equation.  Thus, if  we assume $a/b$ is irreducible, and then show it can be reduced further, then our assumption must be wrong and the second equation is true.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that $a$ and $b$ *must* be coprime; rather, it's that every fraction *can* be written in lowest terms, and this is one possible way to proceed with the proof. Among all the different ways of writing a fraction, we decide to *choose* one where the numerator and denominator have no common factors.